# How to save for loop inside while loop variable in PHP

Tags: php

I'm really having a hard time to save this loop of mine in my system i need to ask if how many style they need for example they chose 3.. there's 3 table will appear and each table you need to write in quantity..

In my saving here's my codes

```
$numgen = $_POST['numgen']; //number of style (i chose 3 style)


$x= 1;
while($x <= $numgen)
{  

    $elements = array();
  foreach ($_POST['barcode'.$x] as $barcode)
    {



 $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productmaterialnumber where materialnumber = :bid");
            $stmt->execute(array(':bid' => $barcode)) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {   

                $productmaterialnumberID = $row['productmaterialnumberID'];
                $matnum = $row['materialnumber'.$x];
                $color = $row['color'];
                $size = $row['size'];
                $productgenericnumberID = $row['productgenericnumberID'];
                $productstylecodeID = $row['productstylecodeID'];

                $qty = $_POST[$matnum];
                $totalqty += $qty;

                $matnummm[] = $matnum."<br>";
                $quantttt[] = $qty."<br>";
                $sizzeeee[] = $size."<br>";
                $colooor[] = $color."<br>";
           }    

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO barcoderequest(reqID, buyerID, qty, materialnumber, ID, printstatus, division, 
            purrequest, dateadded, vendorID, remarks) 
            VALUES(:field0, :field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :field6, :field7, :field8, :field9, :field10)");
            $stmt->execute(array(':field0' => $defaultreqnum,  ':field1' => $userID, 
            ':field2' => $qty, ':field3' => $matnum, ':field4' => $ID, ':field5' => "Pending", ':field6' => $gennum.$division,
            ':field7' =>"Pending", ':field8' =>$currentdatetime, ':field9' => $vendor, ':field10' => $remarks))  
            or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));    
        }

        $x++;
    }
```

If you notice i inserted `$x` beside `$POST['barcode'.$x]`   `$matnum = $row['materialnumber'.$x]` so i can know the id but its not working but when i remove the `$x` it saves 3 times since i choose 3 style.

Can someone help me? THanks

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['barcode'.$x]  => not a collection so you cant loop over it.

Try this:

```
<?php
$_POST['numgen'] = 3;//For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
$numgen = $_POST['numgen']; 
$_POST["barcode1"] = "1234566789"; //For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
$_POST["barcode2"] = "987654321"; //For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
$_POST["barcode3"] = "147852369"; //For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
$x= 1;
while($x <= $numgen)
{  
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {  //Loop over post instead of individual barcodes
        $x="";
        $barcode="";
        if (strstr($key, 'barcode')) {
            $x = str_replace('barcode', '', $key); //Get barcode number
            $barcode = $value; // Get barcode
        }
        if ( $barcode != "") {
            echo "Barcode".$x." :".$barcode."<br/>";//For testing only (Needs to be removed!)
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM productmaterialnumber where materialnumber = :bid");
            $stmt->execute(array(':bid' => $barcode)) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {   
                $productmaterialnumberID = $row['productmaterialnumberID'];
                $matnum = $row['materialnumber'.$x];
                $color = $row['color'];
                $size = $row['size'];
                $productgenericnumberID = $row['productgenericnumberID'];
                $productstylecodeID = $row['productstylecodeID'];
                $qty = $_POST[$matnum];
                $totalqty += $qty;
                $matnummm[] = $matnum."<br>";
                $quantttt[] = $qty."<br>";
                $sizzeeee[] = $size."<br>";
                $colooor[] = $color."<br>";
            }    
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO barcoderequest(reqID, buyerID, qty, materialnumber, ID, printstatus, division, 
purrequest, dateadded, vendorID, remarks) 
VALUES(:field0, :field1, :field2, :field3, :field4, :field5, :field6, :field7, :field8, :field9, :field10)");
            $stmt->execute(array(':field0' => $defaultreqnum,  ':field1' => $userID, 
                                 ':field2' => $qty, ':field3' => $matnum, ':field4' => $ID, ':field5' => "Pending", ':field6' => $gennum.$division,
                                 ':field7' =>"Pending", ':field8' =>$currentdatetime, ':field9' => $vendor, ':field10' => $remarks))  
                or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));
            $x++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @user5598179 Can you check out my solution and let me know if you have any questions?